# Pandas groupby datetime columns by periods

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, mean

I have the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4,7,9,5],[2,6,5,4,9,8,2],[3,5,3,21,12,6,7],[1,7,8,4,3,4,3]]),
              columns=['9:00:00','9:05:00','09:10:00','09:15:00','09:20:00','09:25:00','09:30:00'])


>>> 9:00:00     9:05:00       09:10:00  09:15:00    09:20:00    09:25:00    09:30:00 ....
a       1          2             3         4           7           9           5
b       2          6             5         4           9           8           2
c       3          5             3         21         12           6           7
d       1          7             8         4           3           4           3
```

I would like to get for each row (e.g a,b,c,d ...) the mean vale between specific hours. The hours are between 9-15, and I want to groupby period, for example to calculate the mean value between 09:00:00 to 11:00:00, between 11- 12, between 13-15 (or any period I decide to).

I was trying first to convert the columns values to datetime format and then I though it would be easier to do this:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns,format="%H:%M:%S")
```

but then I got the columns names with fake year "1900-01-01 09:00:00"...

And also, the columns headers type was object, so I felt a bit lost...

My end goal is to be able to calculate new columns with the mean value for each row only between columns that fall inside the defined time period (e.g 9-11 etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need some period, e.g. each 2 hours:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns,format="%H:%M:%S")

df1 = df.resample('2H', axis=1).mean()
print (df1)
   1900-01-01 08:00:00
0             4.428571
1             5.142857
2             8.142857
3             4.285714
```

If need some custom periods is possible use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns,format="%H:%M:%S")

bins = ['5:00:00','9:00:00','11:00:00','12:00:00', '23:59:59']
dates = pd.to_datetime(bins,format="%H:%M:%S")
labels = [f'{i}-{j}' for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 
df.columns = pd.cut(df.columns, bins=dates, labels=labels, right=False)
print (df)
   9:00:00-11:00:00  9:00:00-11:00:00  9:00:00-11:00:00  9:00:00-11:00:00  \
0                 1                 2                 3                 4   
1                 2                 6                 5                 4   
2                 3                 5                 3                21   
3                 1                 7                 8                 4   

   9:00:00-11:00:00  9:00:00-11:00:00  9:00:00-11:00:00  
0                 7                 9                 5  
1                 9                 8                 2  
2                12                 6                 7  
3                 3                 4                 3
```

And last use `mean` per columns, reason of NaNs columns is columns are categoricals:

```
df2 = df.mean(level=0, axis=1)
print (df2)
   9:00:00-11:00:00  5:00:00-9:00:00  11:00:00-12:00:00  12:00:00-23:59:59
0          4.428571              NaN                NaN                NaN
1          5.142857              NaN                NaN                NaN
2          8.142857              NaN                NaN                NaN
3          4.285714              NaN                NaN                NaN
```

For avoid `NaN`s columns convert columns names to strings:

```
df3 = df.rename(columns=str).mean(level=0, axis=1)
print (df3)
   9:00:00-11:00:00
0          4.428571
1          5.142857
2          8.142857
3          4.285714
```

EDIT: Solution above with timedeltas, because format `HH:MM:SS`:

```
df.columns = pd.to_timedelta(df.columns)
print (df)
   0 days 09:00:00  0 days 09:05:00  0 days 09:10:00  0 days 09:15:00  \
0                1                2                3                4   
1                2                6                5                4   
2                3                5                3               21   
3                1                7                8                4   

   0 days 09:20:00  0 days 09:25:00  0 days 09:30:00  
0                7                9                5  
1                9                8                2  
2               12                6                7  
3                3                4                3
```

---

```
bins = ['9:00:00','11:00:00','12:00:00']
dates = pd.to_timedelta(bins)
labels = [f'{i}-{j}' for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 
df.columns = pd.cut(df.columns, bins=dates, labels=labels, right=False)
print (df)
   9:00:00-11:00:00  9:00:00-11:00:00  9:00:00-11:00:00  9:00:00-11:00:00  \
0                 1                 2                 3                 4   
1                 2                 6                 5                 4   
2                 3                 5                 3                21   
3                 1                 7                 8                 4   

   9:00:00-11:00:00  9:00:00-11:00:00  9:00:00-11:00:00  
0                 7                 9                 5  
1                 9                 8                 2  
2                12                 6                 7  
3                 3                 4                 3
```

---

```
#missing values because not exist datetimes between 11:00:00-12:00:00
df2 = df.mean(level=0, axis=1)
print (df2)
   9:00:00-11:00:00  11:00:00-12:00:00
0          4.428571                NaN
1          5.142857                NaN
2          8.142857                NaN
3          4.285714                NaN

df3 = df.rename(columns=str).mean(level=0, axis=1)
print (df3)
   9:00:00-11:00:00
0          4.428571
1          5.142857
2          8.142857
3          4.285714
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. on the first example of the 2H, I get weird hours that are not exist in my dataframe (like 00:00:00 .02:00:00 ) though I have only between 9-15.  on the second part, for some reason the last hour in  bins aleays get NaN and i'm not sure why to do df.rename().mean(), like why do we calculate the mean twice?

Comment: @Reut - For first pandas create ranges by 2H starting by `0`, so it looks like need custom labels like in secon d soluion.

Comment: @Reut - How working is use `, right=True` ?

Comment: @jezreal i'm sorry but I don't understand your answer, can you try to explain what do you mean rehard costum labels and the right=True - wehere?

Comment: @Reut - Ok, what are your `bins` in real data solution?

Comment: ['09:00:00','11:00:00','13:00:00','15:00:00']

Comment: @Reut - so what is maximal datetime after `df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns,format="%H:%M:%S")` and minimal? `print (df.columns.max())`  and `print (df.columns.min())`  ?

Comment: min - Timestamp('1900-01-01 01:00:00')     max: Timestamp('1900-01-01 12:57:00') . That  makes me suspect that the datetime change hours written like 13:00  to 01:00:00

Comment: @Reut - yop, so need change bins to `['01:00:00','09:00:00','11:00:00','13:00:00']` ? And resaon why NaN for last group means there is no datetimes between 13:00:00 to  15:00:00

Comment: @jezreal that is a problem as I want to know the mean between lets say 11-13, and 1 confuses it ("ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.")

Comment: @Reut - Error means need sorted list bins, so `['01:00:00','09:00:00','11:00:00','13:00:00']` should working but `['01:00:00','13:00:00','11:00:00','09:00:00']` not.

Comment: but I am not suppose to have 01:00:00 in my dataframe, I have only 13:00, and after converting columns to datetime  the 13:00 disaapeard and I get only 01:00

Comment: @Reut - hmm, so it convert wrong datetimes?

Comment: @Reut - If use `df.columns = pd.to_timedelta(df.columns)` then working correct print (df.columns.max()) and print (df.columns.min())?

Comment: @Reut - Added solution with timedeltas.

Comment: @Reut - Wrong means incorrect parsing value to datetime or to timedelta in first step?

Comment: the hours values are wrong and for that reason it ffails as it changes 13:00 to 1 and then can't find the mean between them

Answer (score 0):

I am going to show you my code and the results after the ejecution.

First import libraries and dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4,7,9,5],[2,6,5,4,9,8,2],[3,5,3,21,12,6,7], 
[1,7,8,4,3,4,3]]),
          columns= 
         ['9:00:00','9:05:00','09:10:00','09:15:00','09:20:00','09:25:00','09:30:00'])
```

It would be nice create a class in order to define what is a period:

```
class Period():
    def __init__(self,initial,end):
        self.initial=initial
        self.end=end

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.initial +' -- ' +self.end
```

With comand .loc we can get a subdataframe with the columns that I desire:

```
       `def get_colMean(df,period):
           df2 = df.loc[:,period.initial:period.end]
           array_mean = df.mean(axis=1).values

           col_name = 'mean_'+period.initial+'--'+period.end
           pd_colMean = pd.DataFrame(array_mean,columns=[col_name])

           return pd_colMean`
```

Finally we use .join in orde to add our column with the means to our original dataframe:

```
def join_colMean(df,period):
    pd_colMean = get_colMean(df,period)
    df = df.join(pd_colMean)
    return df
```

I am goint to show you my results:
[image]

Comment: there is problem with the dates and hours , if I don't change it to datetime I get keyerror and if I change it to datetime I get  OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 09:05:00

Comment: @Reut What is the error if you don't change it to datetime??